# Run gcloud without sudo

Tags: macos, sudo, gcloud

I'm on Mac OSX and I've always had to run the gcloud command with `sudo`. I can usually work around it, but it has started to cause me some issues. I tried following this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72267/how-to-allow-execution-without-prompting-for-password-using-sudo), but I am not sure where the gcloud command gets called from. It's not in `/usr/bin`.

I have found that my gcloud sdk is installed  at `/Users/Max/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/`, and I have tried adding `/bin/gcloud` and '/lib/gcloud.py' from that path. No luck! Any idea how I can give `NOPASSWD` permissions to this command?

Comment: What is the error message when you run 'gcloud info' without sudo?

Comment: @GlennFowler I solved this problem. All I had to do was point at the gcloud binary  using `sudo visudo`. I'm not sure why it did not work the first time I tired it.

Comment: @Max, as per your last message seems you have already resolved the issue. I would recommend to post as answer, with steps, so that other community member can be benefited.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue myself. [This article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72267/how-to-allow-execution-without-prompting-for-password-using-sudo) was very helpful. Ultimately, you just have to add `sudo` privileges to the `gcloud` command. You will have to give those permissions by running `sudo visudo` and adding a line in the following format:

```
<yourusername> ALL=NOPASSWD: <command1>, <command2>
```

Mine line ended up looking like this:

```
Max ALL=NOPASSWD: /Users/Max/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
```

The part that tripped me up was figuring out where the gcloud command was installed. You have to add that path at the end of the permissions. You can find out where it is installed by running `which gcloud`.

Comment: This fix seems like a bit of workaround to the core problem. I think that giving a process sudo access without requiring a password is a security "no-no". I'm surprised a *nix OS even allows this, but good to know about.

Answer (score 6):

I'm on macOS and my issue was that my `google-cloud-sdk` install folder and it's config folder at `~/.config/gcloud` were owned by `root`. The fix is to `sudo chown -R <your-username> google-cloud-skd` and `sudo chown -R <your-username> ~/.config/gcloud`. And done: no more `sudo`.